# How do I pull multiple IPs from a multi-line log?

Tags: regex

Regex flavor is PCRE

I have a multi-line log that I'm trying to pull IPs from. Sometimes there's one IP listed and sometimes there are multiple IPs listed with comma as the delimiter. I had a regex that was working pulling one or more IPs, but the problem was that I needed to add additional conditions to pull the multiple IPs from one type of event only

I've been trying a ton of different regexes on regex101.com to no avail

```
Token\sType:(?:\n|.)*Client\sIP:\s+(?<adfs_src>:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(\K,)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

ADFS log example:

```
Microsoft ADFS logs and here is an example: 05/07/2019 03:06:54 PM LogName=Security SourceName=AD FS Auditing EventCode=411 EventType=0 Type=Information ComputerName=x.y.z User=abc Sid=A-9-3-98-1231231313-1231231313-1231231313-406293 SidType=1 TaskCategory=Printers OpCode=Info RecordNumber=###### Keywords=Audit Failure, Classic Message=Token validation failed. See inner exception for more details. Additional Data Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Token Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/identitymodel/tokens/UserName Client IP: 10.1.1.1,10.1.1.2  Error message: user@foo.com -The user name or password is incorrect Exception details: System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: user@foo.com ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The user name or password is incorrect at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.LsaLogonUserHelper.GetLsaLogonUserHandle(SafeHGlobalHandle pLogonInfo, Int32 logonInfoSize, SafeCloseHandle& tokenHandle, SafeLsaReturnBufferHandle& profileHandle) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.LsaLogonUserHelper.GetLsaLogonUserInfo(SafeHGlobalHandle pLogonInfo, Int32 logonInfoSize, DateTime& nextPasswordChange, DateTime& lastPasswordChange, String authenticationType, String issuerName) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.LsaLogonUserHelper.GetLsaLogonUser(UserNameSecurityToken token, DateTime& nextPasswordChange, DateTime& lastPasswordChange, String issuerName) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.MSISWindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenInternal(SecurityToken token) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.MSISWindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenInternal(SecurityToken token) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.MSISWindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.LsaLogonUserHelper.GetLsaLogonUserHandle(SafeHGlobalHandle pLogonInfo, Int32 logonInfoSize, SafeCloseHandle& tokenHandle, SafeLsaReturnBufferHandle& profileHandle) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.LsaLogonUserHelper.GetLsaLogonUserInfo(SafeHGlobalHandle pLogonInfo, Int32 logonInfoSize, DateTime& nextPasswordChange, DateTime& lastPasswordChange, String authenticationType, String issuerName) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.LsaLogonUserHelper.GetLsaLogonUser(UserNameSecurityToken token, DateTime& nextPasswordChange, DateTime& lastPasswordChange, String issuerName) at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Tokens.MSISWindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenInternal(SecurityToken token)
```

Looking for a regex that works when either one or more IPs are listed for Client IP

Thx

Comment: Can you add some example data to your question and add what should match?

Comment: Can you show some samples of the log and what should be matched and what should not be matched?

Comment: Microsoft ADFS logs and here is an example:
`05/07/2019 03:06:54 PM LogName=Security SourceName=AD FS Auditing EventCode=411 EventType=0 Type=Information ComputerName=x.y.z User=abc Sid=A-9-3-98-1231231313-1231231313-1231231313-406293 SidType=1 TaskCategory=Printers OpCode=Info RecordNumber=###### Keywords=Audit Failure, Classic Message=Token validation failed. See inner exception for more details. Additional Data Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Token Type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/identitymodel/tokens/UserName Client IP: x.x.x.x,x.x.x.x`

Comment: I just need to pull the IP, or IPs if more than one is listed, but I need to make sure Token Type is in the log as well so I'm not pulling IPs from other event types

Comment: Try 2 capturing groups https://regex101.com/r/lrtWPU/1 And can you add that example to your question?

Comment: Not working and perhaps it's because after the IPs there are additional K/V information listed - thx

Comment: Can you add an example with multiple ips?

Comment: Modified log example in question to include two IPs - thx

Comment: Perhaps like this then https://regex101.com/r/M1Auj4/1

Comment: Perhaps the copy/paste is killing the format - take a look at https://regex101.com/r/9n9RS7/2

Comment: Try this then https://regex101.com/r/tmKHt0/1

Comment: Looks great - only question left I have is where would I add the capture group name of <adfs_src> for the IPs?
Thx again

Comment: Just name the capturing group https://regex101.com/r/tmKHt0/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of repetitive matches using `\G` to match Token Type and multiple occurrences of the ip numbers:

```
(?:(^Token\sType):\s*(?:\n(?!Client IP:).*)+\nClient IP:\s*\n|\G)(?<adfs_src>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(?:[,\s]|$)
```

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(Token\sType)` capture in group 1
  - `(?:\n(?!Client IP:).*)+` Match while line if it does not start with Client IP:
  - `\nClient IP:\s*\n` Match newline, Client IP: then whitespace chars and newline
  - `|` Or
  - `\G` Assert position at then end of previous match
  - `(?<adfs_src>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})` Capture in group adfs_src an 'ip like' format (Note that this does not validate an ip itself)
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(?:[,\s]|$)` Match either a comma, whitespace character or assert the end of the string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0dQrN/1)

If you want the ip numbers including the comma's you could use:

```
(Token\sType):\s+\S+ Client IP: (?<adfs_src>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:,(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mC6dgf/1)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `x` with `\d{1,3`

`(?s)Token\sType:.*?Client\sIP:\s+(?|(?<adfs_src>:x(?:\.x){3})|x(?:\.x){3},\K(?<adfs_src>x(?:\.x){3}))`

https://regex101.com/r/iw4Hm7/1

Readable regex

```
 (?s)
 Token \s Type:
 .*? 
 Client \s IP: \s+ 

 (?|
      (?<adfs_src>                  # (1 start)
           :x (?: \.x ){3}
      )                             # (1 end)
   |  
      x (?: \.x ){3}
      , \K 
      (?<adfs_src>                  # (1 start)
           x (?: \.x ){3}
      )                             # (1 end)
 )
```

---

*PS. I had to verify 7 screens of check crosswalks.
SO also logs me off when I go to regex101.com then close that window.*

*Note - I did add a  "MVPS HOSTS file" (440 k) the other day to stave off ads.

I haven't reverted to old hosts file to test that this behavior doesn't

happen, maybe in the future I will.*